# Handling sessions and remembering logged in user with vertx

Tags: java, java-8, vert.x

Currently when a user logs in to my web server using a web `POST` form, a custom authenticator and a custom user. I have the `CustomUser` put into the `Session` provided by the `RoutingContext` because, when using `RoutingContext#setUser` it only changes the user for that request and as soon as the user is redirected from the login processing page to their destination the `CustomUser` has been lost.

However, it also seems as though the `Session` in `RoutingContext` for the new page doesn't have any user stored in the entry where the auth placed the `CustomUser`, could this be sending a completely different `Session`?

`Routing`:

```
    //ROUTE DEFINITIONS
    //  SESSION AND COOKIE
    router.route().handler(SessionHandler.create(LocalSessionStore.create(vertx)).setNagHttps(false)); //TODO SSL
    router.route().handler(CookieHandler.create());
    //  STATIC
    router.route("/").handler(new StaticHandler()); //BASE
    router.route("/admin").handler(new StaticHandler()); //ADMIN PAGE
    //  FORM REQUESTS
    router.route("/login").handler(new AuthAndRegHandler(new CustomAuth(), dbController)); //LOGIN REQUEST
    router.route("/logout").handler(new AuthAndRegHandler(new CustomAuth(), dbController)); //LOGOUT REQUEST
    //  AJAX
    router.route("/ajax/updateInvoice").handler(new AjaxHandler());
    //  ERRORS
    router.route().failureHandler(new ErrorHandler());
    router.route().handler(handle -> {
        handle.fail(404);
    });
    //END DEFINITIONS
```

`AuthAndRegHandler`:

```
public class AuthAndRegHandler extends AuthHandlerImpl {

    private DatabaseController db;
    private CustomAuth authProvider;

    public AuthAndRegHandler(CustomAuth authProvider, DatabaseController db) {
        super(authProvider);
        this.db = db;
        this.authProvider = authProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(RoutingContext event) {
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
        HttpServerResponse response = event.response();
        HttpServerRequest request = event.request();
        Session session = event.session();
        String requestedPath = request.path();

        authProvider.setJdbc(db.getJdbc()); //returns a JDBCClient

        if(requestedPath.equalsIgnoreCase("/login")) {
            if(request.method() != HttpMethod.POST)
                event.fail(500);
            else {
                request.setExpectMultipart(true);
                request.endHandler(handle -> {
                    MultiMap formAtts = request.formAttributes();
                    String email = formAtts.get("email");
                    String pw = formAtts.get("password");

                    log.info(email + ":" + pw + " login attempt");

                    authProvider.authenticate(new JsonObject()
                            .put("username", email)
                            .put("password", pw), res -> {
                                if(res.succeeded()) {
                                    CustomUser userToSet = (CustomUser) res.result();

                                    session.put("user", userToSet);
                                    log.info("Login successful for " + email);
                                    response.putHeader("Location", "/").setStatusCode(302).end();
                                } else {
                                    event.fail(500);
                                    log.error("Auth error for " + request.host());
                                }
                            });
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`CustomAuth` returns true every time for testing purposes.

`StaticHandler`

```
    CustomUser user = session.get("user");
    event.setUser(user);
    response.putHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");

    if(user != null) {
        log.info(user.principal().getString("email") + " user detected");
        event.setUser(user);
    } else 
        log.info("Null user request detected"); //Constantly outputs, even after a login form has been submitted
```

I'm not entirely sure what's going wrong here. Vertx has sub-optimal documentation for a rookie like myself on session and handling things without their out-of-the-box implementations. Any help on how to log someone in and maintain their session like a normal website would be appreciated.

Comment: In your example you omitted the way you create session store. Could you please add those lines, as I think that the problem may be there. Also, although Vert,x documentation is not very verbose, I think that their examples are pretty good. Did you have a look at this one? https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/web-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/web/sessions/Server.java

Comment: @AlexeySoshin I've added the routing code and you were right in that that's where the problem lay - CookieHandler and SessionHandler are the wrong way round. If you want to add a solution I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who stumble upon the same problem, but usually skip the comments:

Vert.x SessionHandler depends on CookieHandler, and the order is important here.

From the [Vert.x examples](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_handling_sessions):

```
router.route().handler(CookieHandler.create());
router.route().handler(sessionHandler);
```